# Slick Slider responsive breakpoints width is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have created slider using slick slider. The issue I have is that the width of the working fine with breakpoints for online.

However the same code is not working when I write in normal [html file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5956e85a6b3cc1b3ee55d7d34dc997cc20200408134942/be7337). Can any one help me with this. Check from inspect and see for both normal and online code.

```js
let slider = $(".slider");

slider.not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  autoplay: false,
  infinite: true,
  vertical: false,
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  customPaging: function(slider, i) {},
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: false,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }]
});
```

```css
.slide-img {
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
}

.main-title {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.know-more {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.know-more:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.know-more img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px !important;
}

.text-xs-center {
  text-align: center !important;
  padding: 40px 15px !important;
}

.slider {
  width: auto;
  margin: 30px;
}

.slider .slick-slide {
  background: #292e3e;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
  text-align: center;
}

.slider .slick-prev:before,
.slider .slick-next:before {
  color: #292e3e;
}

.slider .slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #57C09F;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: initial !important;
}

.slick-dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6px !important;
  height: 6px !important;
  background: #cccccc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active {
  background: #26d400;
  width: 31px !important;
  height: 6px !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css'>

<section class="slider">
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://webfeb.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/logo-design-for-it-company.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 1</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://cdn5.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/08/04/umbrella-protection-company-logo-concept-vector-2740804.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 2</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://webfeb.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/digital-world-design.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 3</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/mahabiru/mahabiru1601/mahabiru160100044/50770590-business-corporate-letter-d-logo-design-vector-.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 4</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/hartgraphic/hartgraphic1712/hartgraphic171200016/92243101-digital-cube-icon-.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 5</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="text-xs-center">
    <img class="slide-img" src="https://previews.123rf.com/images/putracetol/putracetol1701/putracetol170100016/69776339-digital-cube-logo.jpg">
    <h2 class="main-title">HEAD TITLE 6</h2>
    <h3 class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</h3>
    <a class="know-more" href="#">LEARN MORE<img src="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/141-1415295_red-right-arrow-hd-png-download.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</section>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js'></script>
```

I mean in [codepen](https://codepen.io/pavankumar_kori/pen/abvowxV) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bh6eop5f/).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. After debugging a bit, I found the sizes in HTML were bigger than screen width. Adding the following line to header section fixed my issue:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

Answer (score 1):

switch arrows' value from false to true for all breakpoints and it should work, as it worked for me. or copy the code:

```
let slider = $(".slider");

slider.not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  autoplay: false,
  infinite: true,
  vertical: false,
  dots: true,
  arrows: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  customPaging: function(slider, i) {},
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }, {
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }, {
    breakpoint: 480,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      vertical: false,
    },
  }]
});
```

In CSS change the width of the carousel (image-slider):

```
.slider {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: No its working in noermal html file in local file in computer. But its working in codepen and JDFiddle. I means the width in codepen is taking correctly according to the screen size but in local its taking desktop width size.

Comment: Yes, it is taking full desktop width because it is supposed to do so. If you want your carousel (image-slider) size was smaller than the full width of the screen, then you can set the width yourself. See updated answer.